# Converting multiple .csv files into .dta using a loop

Tags: loops, stata

I have a directory which contains 18 .csv files. I would like to convert all of them to .dta before cleaning the data and appending all of the data. This is the code I have so far:

```
cd "/Volumes/Extreme SSD/secure/TQIP/2007/PUF AY 2007/CSV"
mkdir "stata"
clear
local myfilelist : dir . files"*.csv"

foreach file of local myfilelist {
    drop _all
    insheet using "`file'", comma
    local outfile = subinstr("`file'",".csv","",.)
    save "`outfile'", replace
}
```

I would like to instead save all of the new .dta files into the separate subdirectory "stata" that I created in the second line. Any ideas on how to incorporate into the loop?

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of the main folder using a local. And then use the local to work with the absolute file paths in each read/save operation. I my team's experience `cd` is error prone if you work in multiple projects and should therefore be avoided. See below:

```
local csv_directory "/Volumes/Extreme SSD/secure/TQIP/2007/PUF AY 2007/CSV"
mkdir "`csv_directory'/stata"
clear
local myfilelist : "`csv_directory'" files "*.csv"

foreach file of local myfilelist {
    insheet using "`csv_directory'/`file'", comma clear
    local outfile = subinstr("`file'",".csv","",.)
    save "`csv_directory'/stata/`outfile'", replace
}
```

Also, use `insheet ,clear` instead of `drop _all` if all you want to do is to allow Stata to replace the data in memory with new data.